# retrieve a variable value of a div in a database

Tags: php, database, variables, microphone

I try to retrieve a variable value of a div (height) in order to put it in a table of a database in real-time (I absolutely need it). The value of the height is reacting with the microphone of the device. I would scream in the mic of a computer and see the result on another computer. Is there a simple way to do it?

Thanks.

EDIT : Actually I bring back the sound informations with JRecorder (sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery). The height of the div is equivalent to the amplitude of the scream. I would put the value of this height in a simple table.

Comment: Huh? How did we go from talking about division heights to screaming in a microphone? What do the two have to do with each other at all?

Comment: You could use ajax and post the new height to another page that saves it to a database whenever your div changes size.

Comment: Does the div represent a frequency slice to measure amplitude or something like that?

Comment: @Bastien: please give more useful information about your question. A sample of the HTML code at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to throw in some JavaScript in there. I'll use jQuery in my examples.

To get the height of the div, you can use `getClientRects`.

```
var height = $("#yourdiv")[0].getClientRects()[0].height; //For IE, substract the bottom property from the top property
```

To send it to the server, you can use AJAX

```
$.post("yourpage.php", {height: height});
```

In your server PHP page, you can then retrieve the value and store it in the DB:

```
$height = $_POST['height'];
```

You now have the value in your database. For another client to see it, you need to make a page that display the latest value and poll that page with AJAX at a set interval to get the value and update your `div`.

There is no *simple* way to do this. This is the most simple I could think of. It still requires a good bit of knowledge of JavaScript and AJAX. If you have any questions leave a comment.

Comment: I have always a problem with the code,

the script :
<script>
function ajaxFunction(){
 var height = $("#levelbar")[0].getClientRects()[0].height;
  $.post("acceptfile.php", {height: height});  
}
</script>

the php:

<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";
$dbname = "cheer";

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
$height = $_POST['height'];
$height = mysql_real_escape_string($height);
$query = "SELECT * FROM level WHERE height = '$height'";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>

Do yo know where's my mistake?

Comment: @Bastien I'm sorry. If you're having a specific problem, you'd be better off posting it in another question with the code and what it's supposed to do and all that.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't do anything with your device (microphone), as it's server-side software, not client-side

I didn't get your first part of question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using jRecorder Plugin, you can use the callback function to decide the mic activity level.

callback_activityLevel : Callback for returning current mic input level (0-100)

You can check the example at: http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/example1.html